# Selection with right mouse button in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, select, drag-and-drop, right-click

I have a table view with the following selection settings:

```
setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

This way I can select several rows by clicking and hovering left mouse button.

However this behavior conflicts with dragging and dropping, that's what we see for example in Windows Explorer.

I want to allow users to select rows with **right** mouse button, and drag'n'drop them with their left mouse button (like in Total Commander).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, subclass whatever built-in table view you are using (probably `QTableView`), and reimplement `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` and `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` to modify the current selection.

Comment: I do have a subclass, I just thought there could be an easier option. Redefining mouse events requires both prohibiting selection with left mouse button as well as implementing right mouse button selection.